# How to run a function line by line/How to run a function Asynchronously?

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am trying to run this function sequentially. The output should be:

> latitude length,
> lat length A,
> lat length B

But the output I am getting is:

> latitude length,
> lat length B,
> lat length A

I want to process `this.adminService.getUserList().subscribe(res => {}` first but it is getting processed after the completion of `makeAnAPICall()` function.
My code is below:

```
 async makeAnAPICall():void {
     console.log("latitude length",this.latitude.length);
     this.latitude = [];
     this.longitude = [];
     delay(2000);

    await this.adminService.getUserList().subscribe(res => {
       for(let i =0; i < res.length; i++) {
         this.latitude.push(res[i].latitude);
         this.longitude.push(res[i].longitude);
       };
       console.log("lat length A",this.latitude.length)
     }); 
        
     console.log("lat length B ",this.latitude.length);
  }
```

Comment: RxJS `Subscription` are not Promises. `await`ing them doesn't do what you think  nor anything useful. You have to use callbacks to work with observables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your observable to promise first.

```
async makeAnAPICall():void {
     console.log("latitude length",this.latitude.length);
     this.latitude = [];
     this.longitude = [];
     delay(2000);
     const res = await this.adminService.getUserList().first().toPromise();
   
       for(let i =0; i < res.length; i++) {
         this.latitude.push(res[i].latitude);
         this.longitude.push(res[i].longitude);
       };
       console.log("lat length A",this.latitude.length)
     console.log("lat length B ",this.latitude.length);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now perfectly :)